# Error handling in RxJs combineLatest

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, rxjs, observable, combinelatest

I am using rxJs to retrieve and store data across my app. 
I have a scenario that I’m trying to subscribe to multiple observables using combineLatest. 
The problem is that if some of the observables throws an error I am having trouble to subscribe since the subscribe function doesn’t fire. 
I tried to add .catch(err => err) to the end of each single observable but then the combineLatest.subscribe doesn’t work.

Comment: Post some code for better understanding

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: This seems to be an `angular` question, so i have updated the tag from `angularjs` to `angular`.

Comment: can you try combineLatest((obj)=>obj).catch((e)=>Observable.of('some error'))

Comment: Fan, I love you.   It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert observable to promise using toPromise() and use then / catch.

```
combineLatest([api1, api2]).toPromise()
.then(([api1Res, api2Res]) => {
  // do stuff
})
.catch(error => {
 // show error response
}
```